# Get Value From Disabled Textfield Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function pretest() {
      var a = document.getElementById('pre').value;
      var result = parseInt(a);
      if (a <= 50) {
         document.getElementById('val').value = 1;
      }else if(50<a && a<= 80){
        document.getElementById('val').value = 2;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('val').value = 3;
      }
}

    function posttest(){
       var a = document.getElementById('post').value;
      var result = parseInt(a);
      if (a <= 50) {
         document.getElementById('val1').value = 1;
      }else if(50<a && a<= 80){
        document.getElementById('val1').value = 2;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('val1').value = 3;
      }
    }

    function all(){
      var a = document.getElementById('val').value;
      var b = document.getElementById('val1').value;
      var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
      if (!isNaN(c)) {
         document.getElementById('total').value = c;
      }

    }
```

```html
<input onkeyup="pretest();" type="text" id="pre" name="pretest">

<input onkeyup="all();" type="text" id="val" name="val" disabled="disabled">

<input onkeyup="posttest();" type="text" id="post" name="posttest">

<input onkeyup="all();" type="text" id="val1" name="val1" disabled="disabled">

<input onkeyup="total();" type="text" id="total" name="total" disabled="disabled">
```

i have 5 text field

A1  A2(value onkeyup from A1 and disabled is true) 
B1  B2(value onkeyup from B1 and disabled is true)

C(A2+B2 and disabled textfield)

How to get value for C textfield ? i used onkeyup, but didn't work

Comment: Where's your code for reference?

Comment: You get the value of text fields exactly the same way regardless of whether they are disabled or not, through the field's `.value` property.

Comment: why is `php` tagged here? Also OP, you're really going to need to make your query clearer.  Perhaps include the `html` that you currently have

Comment: hai @Mr.Alien my thread was updated

Comment: @DMcCallum83 i'm so sorry

Comment: Your code references a `total` function, but you don't have that.

Comment: Update your UI so that its clear what each text field represents. Then, update your question with clearer explanations of what you want. Right now, your question is not understandable.

Comment: You obviously cannot fire `keyup` (as well as `focus`, `click`, `change`, and others) event on `disabled` input. But you can call `all()` from `pretest` and `posttest` functions (and it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things amiss in your code.

- never, **ever** use `parseInt(foo)` without the radix-argument, **especially** when `foo` is arbitrary input. `parseInt` will otherwise take input `012` and think it's an octal value you gave it. Thus, make that `parseInt(a, 10)` to get a decimal, or use `Number(a)`
- `onkeyup` won't fire on a disabled element - how could it? Nobody will be able to press a key there, since it's disabled. What you probably want is `onchange`, however...
- ...`onchange` (or `oninput`, which is a little more trigger-happy and what I've used below) won't fire when you manually set an element's value; it doesn't in vanilla JS, nor when using jQuery's `val()` - you have to trigger it manually
- your code example is rushed, incomplete and I had to work considerably longer and harder to understand what you want than should be necessary; regardless...

```js
/*
Especially with function names like `all` and `total`, you will want
to make sure to set up some sort of namespacing, e.g. using the 
Revealing Module Pattern or other. These functions are attached to 
the global window object and can be overriden by anything and anybody,
causing at least hard-to-trace bugs, maybe worse
*/

function pretest() {
  var a = document.getElementById('pre').value;
  var result = parseInt(a, 10);
  if (a <= 50) {
    document.getElementById('val').value = 1;
  } else if (50 < a && a <= 80) {
    document.getElementById('val').value = 2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('val').value = 3;
  }

  // you have to explicitly call all() here, as the input-event
  // won't be fired when manually setting value
  all();
}

function posttest() {
  var a = document.getElementById('post').value;
  var result = parseInt(a, 10);
  if (a <= 50) {
    document.getElementById('val1').value = 1;
  } else if (50 < a && a <= 80) {
    document.getElementById('val1').value = 2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('val1').value = 3;
  }

  all()
}

function all() {
  var a = document.getElementById('val').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('val1').value;
  var c = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
  if (!isNaN(c)) {
    document.getElementById('total').value = c;
  }

  total();
}

total = function() {
  //TODO implement
}

document.getElementById('pre').addEventListener('input', window.pretest);
document.getElementById('post').addEventListener('input', window.posttest);
```

```html
<label for="pre">PRE</label><br>
<input type="text" id="pre" name="pretest">
<br><br>
<label for="val">val</label><br>
<input type="text" id="val" name="val" disabled="disabled">
<br><br>
<label for="post">POST</label><br>
<input type="text" id="post" name="posttest">
<br><br>
<label for="val1">val1</label><br>
<input type="text" id="val1" name="val1" disabled="disabled">
<br><br>
<label for="total">TOTAL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value as from normal text input

```js
    

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("textPlace").disabled = true;
console.log(document.getElementById("textPlace").value)

}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="textPlace">
```

Comment: Setting the value is also just assignment to the `.value`-property.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: What do you want then ?

Comment: i have 5 text field

A1 A2(value A2 from A1 with onkeyup event and disabled textfield condition) 
B1 B2(value B2 from B1 with onkeyup event and disabled textfield condition)

C (value C from A2+B2 and disabled textfield condition)

i want get C value

Comment: @ramen Clearly, we don't understand what that means. Edit your question and take the time to explain your scenario.

Comment: My comment wasn't for you. It was for @ramen.

Comment: Same here My comment wasn't for you. It was for @ramen.

Comment: You should direct your comments to a particular person by prefixing it with `@` and the user name unless you are replying to the person who made the post in the first place (as is the case with this comment).

Comment: Thanks, noted @Scott Marcus